# How to see timer status on lock screen with media playing?

Tags: ios, screen-lock, clock

I want to see quickly/easily how much time is left on my timer while audio is playing.

This was possible in previous versions of iOS by pressing home twice. Now in iOS 10, I have to press home, then lift the Control Center, and tap the timer button. Is there no quicker way?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I ask because I can still see the timer on my lock screen, so I'm thinking there may be some relevant detail missing in your question.

Comment: I expanded my last sentence. Does that help? Thank you.